# get the profile of the requested user which is send as a serialized object

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am sending the requested user object to the background task which is responsible for getting the profile of that user and then calculate the completeness of profile. I could send the serialized user object but could not get the profile of that user. How do i do this?

consumers.py

```
class AccountBackgroundTasks(SyncConsumer):
  def calculate_profile_percentage(self, context):
        print("arrived here successfully")
        logger.info("context", context)
        weight = {'full_name': 10, 'age': 10, 'city': 10, 'address': 10}
        total = 0
        try:
            user = context.get('user')
            profile_instance = model_to_dict(Profile.objects.get(user=user))
            for field in profile_instance:
                try:
                    total += weight[field]
                except AttributeError:
                    logger.error("Could not find the field")
                    continue
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            logger.error("Profile does not exist")
            return
        return total
```

query.py

```
@staticmethod
def resolve_profile(self, info, **kwargs):
    print('info', info.context.user)
    # type <class 'apps.accounts.models.User'>
    print('type', type(info.context.user))
    if info.context.user.is_authenticated:
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        print("channel_layer", channel_layer)
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('accounts', {
            'type': 'calculate.profile.percentage',
            'text': serializers.serialize('json', [info.context.user, ])
        })
        return Profile.objects.get(user=info.context.user)
    return None
```

Comment: Better just send the pk of the user and retrieve it from the db in the consumer as this is a message passing across processes and trying to serialize the model object isn't a good idea

Comment: can you post it in answer section so that i can mark it as solved, please?

Comment: I have done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better just send the pk of the user and retrieve it from the db in the consumer as this is a message passing across processes and trying to serialize the model object isn't a good idea

Comment: if i pass only id then to get the profile of that user first i need to get that user using `User.models.object.get(id=id)` and then Profile instance. Is this fine then?

Comment: @Serenity you can do it with one query `Profile.objects.get(user_id=id)`

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have marked this as solved.

Comment: if you have time, can you look at this problem, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430776/algorithm-to-calculate-the-profile-percentage-complete